# Как с ffmpeg порезать в папке видеофайлы для инстаграм-сторис?

Tags: видео, ffmpeg

Есть в папке много видео файлов *mov. (на скрине их два шт.)

Хочу все эти *mov файлы порезать для инстаграм видео-сторис длинной по 59 секунд (неважно на каком кадре резать). По итогу получится оч мнооооого видеофайлов по 59 секунд.

[image: скрин]

Хочу порезать чтоб каждый итоговый видеофайл имел такие параметры:

```
MP4 Container format
H.264 Video Codec
AAC Audio
3500kbps bitrate
30 FPS
60 seconds maximum in length
1080p 9:16 ( 1080 х 1920 px)
```

Сделал для ffmpeg такой батник:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mov) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf scale=ih*9/16:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1,scale=-2:1080 -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -x264-params scenecut=0:open_gop=0:min-keyint=72:keyint=72 -c:a aac -preset slow -crf 23 -r 30 -sn -f segment -segment_time 59 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y "%%~ni.mp4"

)
pause
```

Как побороть ошибку, как я понял что-то с именами файлов? Скрин ошибки:
[image: скрин]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По примеру из документации

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -force_key_frames  "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" -f segment -segment_time 59 -reset_timestamps 1 out%03d.mp4
```

Но я бы добавил ещё `-force_key_frames  "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)"` чтоб не было заметно серых артефактов в момент склейки.

upd. Убрал faststart потому как он наверняка не нужен тут. Добавил `-reset_timestamps 1` чтоб счётчик времени видео шел с 0.

Comment: @echo off
for %%i in (*.mov) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf scale=ih*9/16:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1,scale=-2:1080, -f segment -segment_time 59 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)"' -y "out%03d.mp4"

)
pause



Получил ошибку (скрин): https://prnt.sc/BZ82zspj4wEP

Comment: так убери запятую в конце списка фильтров)

Comment: убрал ковычку '  после "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)"
  Код:
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mov) do (
ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf scale=ih*9/16:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1,scale=-2:1080, -f segment -segment_time 59 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" -y "out%03d.mp4"
)
pause

но ошибка:
https://prnt.sc/3QORVkn6Zakb

Comment: убери запятую в конце списка фильтров

Comment: убрал , теперь ошибка с именем файла. Код:
`@echo off
for %%i in (*.mov) do (
  ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf scale=ih*9/16:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1,scale=-2:1080 -f segment -segment_time 59 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" -y "out%03d.mp4"

)
pause`

Ошибка:
https://prnt.sc/GBO0tupSqGSA

Comment: `%03d` испортился виндовым cmd. `%%03d` попробуй https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122418/2101808

Comment: Батник работает всего с одним видеофайлом из папки. Как он с этим файлом работает: рубит его на несколько кусков, каждый итоговый кусок длинее предыдущего итогового куска на 59 секунд. То есть файлы получаются продолжительностью: 59 сек, 118 сек, 177сек и так далее. Вот на схеме я изобразил: https://prnt.sc/77ooQrX8D3t8 Код: `@echo off for %%i in (*.mov) do ( ffmpeg -i "%%i" -vf scale=ih*9/16:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1,scale=-2:1080 -f segment -segment_time 59 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" -y "%%03d.mp4" )`

Comment: а, эту особенность не учел. на самом деле длинна видео получается 59 сек, но в начале пауза на время начала сегмента - она нужна для ровной перемотки в html5 плеере. как исправить добавил в ответ

Comment: Кстати, подскажите а как сделать чтоб батник не перезаписывал полученные куски от одного видео, новыми кусками полученными от следующего видео? Т.к. сейчас он пятиминутное видео порубил на 5 кусков с именами:  000.mp4, 001.mp4, 002.mp4, 003.mp4, 004.mp4  ......потом перешел к следующему видео и порубил его на куски с теми же именами 000.mp4, 001.mp4, 002.mp4, 003.mp4, 004.mp4

Comment: И еще один интересный момент, скрипт делает первое видео длинной не 59 секунд , а 62 секунды, остальные как положено по 59 сек. Уже всю голову сломал, как без ущерба для корректной работы убрать эти лишние 3 сек?))

Comment: у меня 66 сек))

Comment: чтоб не переписывал в место слова out(у меня)  или перед %%003 в шаблоне поставьте счётчик с батника

Comment: @MikhailEliseev  if these starting frames aren't keyframes, ffmpeg will start the segment with the first keyframe found after these frames.  Следовательно  -force_key_frames "expr: gte(t, n_forced * 0.5)" нужно переместить до сегментации. - тогда режет точно) но тут ещё есть простор для оптимизаций